# NLog how to write message source

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I'd like to log the class information who called the log method.

```
Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
Logger.Info("Start");
```

I'd like to see in the log the full class name of the class that execute the code above.

I saw in [NLog documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target) where is mentioned a `source` option, but it is not so clear how to use it and if it fits my requirements.

This is what I would like to see:

> 2019-11-11 15:07:19.6935 DefaultLogger MyProject.Program INFO Start

where MyProject.Main is the full class name of the class who call the `Logger.Info`.

EDIT:

This is how I configured the logger:

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
var allLogs = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("allLogs");
allLogs.Layout = "${longdate} ${logger} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}";
allLogs.FileName = basePath + "/${shortdate}.log";
config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, allLogs));
config.AddTarget(allLogs);

LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Comment: Show us your NLog.config file?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany configuration added

Comment: Would the [callsite layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer) be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Fildor yes it is! I searched with the wrong keyword. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: NLog has a very helpful overview of available renderers: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [callsite layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer) seems to match your requirement:

> The call site (class name, method name and source information).

Mind: *"Not supported on NetStandard 1.3"*

Syntax:

```
${callsite:className=Boolean:fileName=Boolean:includeSourcePath=Boolean:methodName=Boolean}
```

---

For your information: There is an excellent overview on available layout renderers [here](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers).

---

By the way: If you use [`LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_GetCurrentClassLogger.htm), then the [`${logger}`](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer) layout renderer will render the fully qualified class name of the class in which the logger was created.

> Gets the logger named after the currently-being-initialized class.